# Insert values and add values to foreign key

Tags: postgresql, insert, cte, sequence, upsert

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE est (
  est_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, est_nom varchar(70)
);

CREATE TABLE bm (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY
, est_nom int
, nom varchar(70)
, CONSTRAINT FK_bm_est FOREIGN KEY(est_nom) REFERENCES est(est_id) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

I want to insert this data in `bm`

```
INSERT INTO bm
VALUES
(netx serial,'DAPR','leopold stotch'),
(netx serial,'LDGA','fredderik gauss'),
(netx serial,'SDCD','edward gortz')
```

Input values in column 2 are strings, corresponding to `est.est_nom`. I need the matching `est.est_id` instead.

I want to get existing values from `est.est_nom` and use them for the insert into `bm.est_id`.

If not found, first insert new rows in `est` and use the resulting serial `est_nom` for the insert into `bm`.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to get IDs from a lookup table, or generate new ones on the fly if missing.
First, sanitize your relational design.

#### Proper design

```
CREATE TABLE est (
  est_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, est_nom varchar(70) UNIQUE NOT NULL  -- must be unique!
);

CREATE TABLE bm (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY
, est_id int                           -- fixed the deceiving name!
, bm_nom varchar(70)
, CONSTRAINT fk_bm_est_id FOREIGN KEY(est_id) REFERENCES est(est_id) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

We need a `UNIQUE` constraint on `est.est_nom` to check for duplicates efficiently. And `bm.est_id` really shouldn't be named `bm.est_nom`. It holds the ID not the name.

Basically, insert new values into `est` returning newly generated IDs in a data-modifying CTE first, then insert into `bm`. Basics:

- [Insert data in 3 tables at a time using Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20561627/939860)

But pre-existing rows and concurrent write access can complicate matters.

#### Concurrent writes not possible

If writes from concurrent transactions to any involved rows are not possible:

```
WITH input AS (  -- input here!
   SELECT e.est_id, i.est_nom, i.bm_nom
   FROM  (                               -- input once here
      VALUES
     ('DAPR','leopold stotch')
   , ('LDGA','fredderik gauss')
   , ('SDCD','edward gortz')
   , ('SDCD','fritz gortz')              -- added row to show duplicate est_nom
   ) i(est_nom, bm_nom)
   LEFT JOIN est e USING (est_nom)
   )
, ins_est AS (
   INSERT INTO est (est_nom)
   SELECT DISTINCT est_nom
   FROM   input i
   WHERE  i.est_id IS NULL
   -- no concurrent writes, so no race condition
   RETURNING est_nom, est_id
   )
INSERT INTO bm (est_id, bm_nom)
SELECT COALESCE(i.est_id, ie.est_id), i.bm_nom
FROM   input i
LEFT   JOIN ins_est ie USING (est_nom)
RETURNING *;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GLKiuTV2)

If there can be duplicate values for `est_nom` in the input (the typical case), then that needs some extra attention. The added `DISTINCT` takes care of it.

Here, I fetch existing IDs first, so we don't burn serial numbers and make it slightly cheaper. This can fail with concurrent write load.

#### Concurrent writes possible

```
WITH input(est_nom, bm_nom) AS (  -- input once here
   VALUES
     ('DAPR','leopold stotch')
   , ('LDGA','fredderik gauss')
   , ('SDCD','edward gortz')
   , ('SDCD','fritz gortz')       -- added row to show duplicate est_nom
   )
, ins_est AS (
   INSERT INTO est (est_nom)
   SELECT DISTINCT est_nom
   FROM   input
   ON     CONFLICT (est_nom) DO UPDATE
   SET    est_nom = EXCLUDED.est_nom
   WHERE  false                    -- only lock existing rows
   RETURNING est_nom, est_id
   )
INSERT INTO bm (est_id, bm_nom)
SELECT COALESCE(e.est_id, ie.est_id), i.bm_nom
FROM   input i
LEFT   JOIN ins_est ie USING (est_nom)
LEFT   JOIN est e USING (est_nom)
RETURNING *;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GLKiuTV2)

Concurrency is a sophisticated matter that needs some understanding.
Concurrency combined with UPSERT in a CTE can get tricky. See:

- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217872/939860)

Comment: hi, Erwin. in, second part: Concurrent writes possible. since already used `DISTINCT est_nom`, there will be no conflict `est_nom`?

Comment: @jian: Multiple input rows can conflict with each other, or with existing table rows. We need to defend against both kinds, separately. I even added a 4th input row in my example to demonstrate the first kind - which is often overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

Join with `est` and don't insert the `id` column, so that it is auto-generated:

```
INSERT INTO bm (est_nom, nom)
SELECT est.est.id, v.nom
FROM est
   JOIN (VALUES
            ('DAPR', 'leopold stotch'),
            ('LDGA', 'fredderik gauss'),
            ('SDCD', 'edward gortz')
        ) AS v(est_nom, nom)
      ON est.est_nom = v.est_nom;
```